# Use JSValue.toObjectOf for typed arrays

Tags: ios, swift, javascriptcore

With `JSExport` of `JavaScriptCore` you can convert a JavaScript object to a Swift object. However I cannot find a way how to convert an array of JavaScript objects to a native Swift array. Therefore I wanted to ask if I am missing something, or if this is just not possible.

### What I've tried

```js
const test = [{ value: 'value1' }, { value: 'value2' }]
```

#### 1. NSArray

```swift
let jsValue = ...
jsValue.toObjectOf(NSArray.self)
```

The downsides of this approach is that I could not specify which JSExport type I want the NSArray to be. The elements of the `NSArray` are dictionaries. This is pretty much the same as I would get with `jsValue.toArray()`.

#### 2. Array

```swift
protocol TestExport: JSExport {
    var value: String { get }
}

class Test: NSObject, TestExport {
    let value: String
    init(value: String) { self.value = value }
}

let jsValue = ...
jsValue.toObjectOf([Test].self)
```

This does not compile because `[Test].Type` is not of type `AnyClass`.

#### 3. ???

Use something like https://github.com/swhitty/KeyValueCoder to parse the result of `toObject()` to a `Codable` struct. However I am not sure if this is the most performant option, since there are extra steps inbetween.

Comment: Interesting question. I guess the root cause here is that `NSArray` isn't generic, so you can't just say `jsValue.toObjectOf(NSArray<Test>.self)`. This is all built on top of Objective C runtime stuff, so I wonder if there's some other hooks for customizing how objects are bridged.